# Lucene and tokens that are too long

Tags: java, lucene

I'm working on a indexer using `Lucene`, and this past week added storing `TermVectors` to the code so I could experiment with feedback and other fun stuff.  Following this step of storing term vectors, I started getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one
>   immense  term in field="f_common.document.text" (whose UTF8 encoding
>   is longer than  the max length 32766), all of which were skipped. 
>   Please correct the   analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix
>   of the first immense term  is: '[34, 60, 97, 99, 114, 101, 58, 98,
>   108, 111, 99, 107, 62, 32, 32, 32,  60, 100, 105, 118, 32, 97, 99,
>   114, 101, 58, 100, 101, 102, 61]...',   original message: bytes can be
>   at most 32766 in length; got 34444

Ok, no problem.  (Well, dying on an overlong token feels like a bug to me, but this was a conscious API move back in 4.8.)  So I added the following `AnalyzerWrapper` to fix the problem:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.LengthFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;

/*
 * Lucene's IndexWriter.addDocument() will pitch an exception if the document contains a token that is too long.
 * I would rather just drop long tokens.
 */

public class SafetyAnalyzer extends AnalyzerWrapper {

    private Analyzer baseAnalyzer;

    public SafetyAnalyzer(Analyzer baseAnalyzer) {
        super(Analyzer.PER_FIELD_REUSE_STRATEGY);
        this.baseAnalyzer = baseAnalyzer;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        baseAnalyzer.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected Analyzer getWrappedAnalyzer(String fieldName) {
        return baseAnalyzer;
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents wrapComponents(String fieldName, TokenStreamComponents components) {
        TokenStream ts = components.getTokenStream();
        LengthFilter drop_long_tokens = new LengthFilter(ts, 0, IndexWriter.MAX_TERM_LENGTH);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(components.getTokenizer(), drop_long_tokens);
    }
}
```

Which should drop long tokens that the `IndexWriter` will barf on. This wraps other analyzers like so:

```
public Analyzer getDefaultIndexAnalyzer() throws Exception {
    if (defaultIndexAnalyzer == null) {
        String defaultAnalyzerName = getConfig("LUCENE_INDEX_ANALYZER_DEFAULT");
        if (defaultAnalyzerName == null)
            defaultAnalyzerName = "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer";
        defaultIndexAnalyzer = new SafetyAnalyzer((Analyzer)Class.forName(defaultAnalyzerName).newInstance());
    }
    return defaultIndexAnalyzer;
}
```

Only, it doesn't work.  I still get `IllegalArgumentExceptions` on those tokens.  The only solution I could find was to catch the IAE on `writer.addDocument()`.

Am I writing the analyzer wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the field is less than the IndexWriter's limit in *characters*, but over the limit in *bytes*.  `LengthFilter` filters out tokens based on their length in characters (UTF-16 code units).  `IndexWriter.MAX_TERM_LENGTH`, on the other hand, is in UTF-8 encoded bytes.

This filter should do what you are looking for.  Works the same as `LengthFilter`, so should be easy to drop something like this into your `SafetyAnalyzer` (It's effectively just a copy of `LengthFilter` with a modified `accept()` method):

```
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;

public final class ByteLengthFilter extends FilteringTokenFilter {

  private final int min;
  private final int max;
  private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

  public ByteLengthFilter(TokenStream in, int min, int max) {
    super(in);
    if (min < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("minimum length must be greater than or equal to zero");
    }
    if (min > max) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("maximum length must not be greater than minimum length");
    }
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept() {
    final int len = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(CharBuffer.wrap(termAtt)).remaining();
    return (len >= min && len <= max);
  }
}
```

A warning:  Not sure what the performance will be like on this in practice.  It's sure to be more expensive than `LengthFilter`, which is just using `CharSequence.length()` to get the length.

Comment: Thank you for the clue.  It might be better to go the other way, compute how many characters I expect to be able to hold for the data that's coming in.  I will try both ways and see what happens.

Comment: @IanSoboroff - Sure, you could safely limit it to `IndexWriter.MAX_TERM_LENGTH / 4`, I believe.